# IIS Rewrite changing ASP.Net HyperLink Backend Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm going crazy, maybe someone here can sort this for me.

Simple rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Pages Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*?)/$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="pages/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
```

It works fine.

So we have example.com/pages/apage.aspx
It's rewritten to example.com/apage/

All working as expected. On this page we have an ASP HyperLink (or a standard A link with runat=server)

But when binding:

HL_CustomizeCollapse.NavigateUrl = "#sample";

Instead of the href being example.com/apage/#sample
The href is being set to: example.com/pages/#sample

So the rewrite rule is affecting the href when the link is set from codebehind. Any links set on the front side are fine. Outbound rules will change those as expected.

This tag is unaffected by outbound rules, and is affected by inbound rules.

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi there! Did you give up with stack overflow? Please come and check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Both `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` and `a.href` setters use `Control.ResolveClientUrl()` to determine the absolute path for a relative path.

`Control.ResolveUrl()`, on the other hand, uses the current template's source virtual directory (which is /aPage) to build the absolute path.

Thus, when the request path `/pages/apage.aspx` is re-written to `/apage/`, and the following code is executed as the result:

### /aPage/default.aspx

```
<div>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="asp_hyperlink_to_default_aspx" runat="server">
        asp_hyperlink_to_default_aspx
    </asp:HyperLink><br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_client_url_default_aspx" runat="server">
        asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_client_url_default_aspx
    </asp:HyperLink><br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_url_default_aspx" runat="server">
        asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_url_default_aspx
    </asp:HyperLink><br />
</div>
```

### /aPage/default.aspx.cs:

```
    Response.Write("<pre>");

    Response.Write("ResolveClientUrl(\"Default.aspx\") = " + ResolveClientUrl("Default.aspx") + "<br/>");
    Response.Write("ResolveUrl(\"Default.aspx\") = " + ResolveUrl("Default.aspx") + "<br/>");
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write("Request.RawUrl = " + Request.RawUrl + "<br/>");
    Response.Write("Request.Url.AbsolutePath = " + Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "<br/>");
    Response.Write("Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = " + Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath + "<br/>");

    asp_hyperlink_to_default_aspx.NavigateUrl = "Default.aspx";
    asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_client_url_default_aspx.NavigateUrl = ResolveClientUrl("Default.aspx");
    asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_url_default_aspx.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("Default.aspx");

    Response.Write("</pre>");
```

The following output is generated:

```
ResolveClientUrl("Default.aspx") = Default.aspx
ResolveUrl("Default.aspx") = /aPage/Default.aspx

Request.RawUrl = /pages/apage.aspx
Request.Url.AbsolutePath = /aPage/default.aspx
Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = ~/aPage/default.aspx

<div>
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_asp_hyperlink_to_default_aspx" href="Default.aspx">
        asp_hyperlink_to_default_aspx
    </a><br />
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_client_url_default_aspx" href="Default.aspx">
        asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_client_url_default_aspx
    </a><br />
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_url_default_aspx" href="/aPage/Default.aspx">
        asp_hyperlink_to_resolve_url_default_aspx
    </a><br />
</div>
```

Therefore, to be on the safe side, it is best to use ResolveUrl() to set the `NavigationUrl` and `href` properties of HyperLink and A, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to be a solution. If you run a debugger when the NavigationURL or href are being assigned in codebehind it's assigning it correctly using any of the three options you listed it. But once it renders to page that link is being re-written by the inbound rewrite rule.

Comment: So did you try ResolveUrl()? It is assigning an absolute path. This should not be altered afterward.

Comment: ResolveUrl() assigns the incorrect url: /pages/#sample in codebehind.
ResolveClientUrl() assigns the incorrect url: ../pages/#sample in codebehind.
NavigateUrl = assignes the correct URL: #sample in codebehind

But on render they are all: /pages/#sample